# Matching cardinality of varargs when passing parameters

Tags: scala, function, parameters

A simple function that accepts a `File` and a function that will be passed a `PrintWriter` for that file:

```
def printToFile(f: java.io.File)(op: java.io.PrintWriter => Unit) {
  val p = new java.io.PrintWriter(f)
  try { op(p) } finally { p.close() }
}
```

How to generalise this to any number of `File`s, while just passing the resulting `PrintWriter`s to one function? I want to make the decision as to which `PrintWriter` to use in the client function.

I want a signature similar to (psuedocode):

```
def printToFile(f: java.io.File*)(op: (java.io.PrintWriter*) => Unit)
```

Here's how I'd like to write my client function:

```
printToFile(new File("file1.txt"), new File("file2.txt"), new File("file3.txt")) { 
    (file1PrintWriter, file2PrintWriter, file3PrintWriter) =>
        // do stuff, decide which PrintWriter to write to
}
```

Where the cardinality of both *ed types are the same.

**Importantly, I want the client function to be able to declare the `PrintWriter` variables it receives** and not just have a `Seq[PrintWriter]` or similar to deal with.

Comment: This is the first solution that comes to my mind, will this work? `def printToFile(f: (java.io.File, java.io.PrintWriter => Unit)*)`

Comment: Thanks, but that requires multiple `PrintWriter => Unit` functions to be specified. I need the client function to decide which `PrintWriter` to use.

Comment: So you only pass one PrintWriter?

Comment: No, one function. In that function, expect as many `PrintWriter`s as there were `File`s passed in.

Comment: Dan, can you give an example of how you want the vararged to behave? Even giving an example of how you may be calling it can be useful. I think the short answer is that using this vararged function definition you will *not* be able to use the type system to enforce equality in cardinality. I can help more when I understand the problem a bit better.

Comment: I added an example of how I'd like to write my client function. Maybe you're right, maybe this is impossible...

Answer (score 0):

I looks like you need to create as many `PrintWriter` instances as the number of arguments. The following should work.

```
import java.io._

object Foo {
  def printToFile(files: File*)(op: (PrintWriter*) => Unit) {
    val printers: Seq[PrintWriter] = files.map(file => new PrintWriter(file))

    try {
      op(printers :_*)
    } finally {
      printers.foreach(_.close)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't compile for numerous reasons but most importantly that `op` is not declared to accept a varargs... is that what you meant?

Comment: I've realised I've missed out a requirement. I want to be able to declare the `PrintWriter`s in the client function... hang on. btw the code still doesn't compile - `p` is a `Seq` so cannot call close on it (you mean `p.foreach(_.close)`) pls should be `new java.io.PrintWriter(_)`

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by being able to declare `PrintWriter`s in the function? Some pseudocode may help.

Comment: See the OP for how I'd like to write the client function.

Comment: The responsibility for creating the `PrintWriter`s should be that of the `printToFile` function as per the OP.

Comment: Dan, why is the suggested snippet above not what you expected? You can call it exactly as you suggest in the OP, i.e. you can define the "client function" anonymously. Is the problem that you want to check that the cardinality of the varargs in `files` and the `op` function match at compile time?

Comment: Because it's just giving me a collection of `PrintWriter`s. I want to declare the instances of the `PrintWriter`s. I suppose if I declared as a `List[PrintWriter]` I could pattern match?